# null pointer exception in custom dialog in android?

Tags: android, customdialog

i am creating alarm application , i have created a custom dialog with edit texts and a save button , when i click save button these data to be saved in DB , but i am getting NULL POINTER EXCEPTION at

```
Savebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        if (v.equals(Savebutton)) {
                            String nameToInsert = (String) uname_ET.getText().toString();
                            String drugnameToInsert = (String) dname_ET.getText().toString();

                            Log.i("Onclick",""+nameToInsert);
                            Log.i("Onclick",""+drugnameToInsert);

                            if (position == 0) 
                            { Log.i("Onclick",""+position); }
                            }
                    }
                });
```

exception at `Savebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()`
i dint get out of error

Comment: 07-13 15:16:42.295: E/AndroidRuntime(666): java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

May be you should check that the edit text is not empty before calling `getText().toString()`..

```
 if(uname_ET.getText() != null) String nameToInsert = (String) uname_ET.getText().toString();
 if(dname_ET.getText() != null) String drugnameToInsert = (String) dname_ET.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

i think problem is this u have set button ,edittext etc ...object this way

```
 Button Savebutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.savebutton);
```

for custome dialog u have to set object as shown below

```
 Button Savebutton=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.savebutton);
```

where dialog is a object as

```
  Dialog dialog = new Dialog(YourActivity.this);
```